# Copying large file with robocopy during VMWare storage vmotion

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-vsphere, robocopy, bottleneck

if I copy massive files via robocopy during storage vmotion then is there any negative impact ?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It will obviously have a little impact on the performance, it will be a little slower, but otherwise it will have no impact.

How much slower depends entirely on the hardware and the abilities of your storage.

Comment: thanks AFAIK , A storage vmotion does an initial copy, then copies any data that has changed (is 'dirty'). This happens multiple times until (hopefully) the amount of dirty data is minimal, and it can freeze IO and move entirely to the new storage.

While doing a file copy you're changing more blocks, and forcing storage vmotion to do more work. So it can be slower, or it might get cancelled entirely. The same applies to live migration / vmotion, if a VM is writing too much data to RAM it can cause the live migration to fail.